# Math notation: What does $I$ mean in this context?

Tags: notation, definition, machine-learning

Sorry if this is a noobish question, but I don't know what $I$ means in this context:

$$\hat{f}(X) = \sum_{m=1}^5 c_m I\{(X_1, X_2) \in R_m\}$$

I am reading about Decision Trees in *The Elements of Statistical Learning*.<sup>1</sup> $I$ isn't introduced<sup>2</sup> so I assume it is a kind of operator on the following set?

Thanks a lot for any explanation!

---

<sup>1</sup> T. Hastie, R. Tibshirani, J. Friedman: *The Elements of Statistical Learning*, second edition, Springer 2009, p. 305.

<sup>2</sup> I haven't worked through the whole book, but at least it isn't introduced in this chapter and there is no general section about notation as far as I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely means the function that is one when the statement within the curly brackets is true, and zero otherwise. i.e. The function $f$ defined by
$$f(X_1, X_2) = I\{(X_1, X_2) \in R_m\}$$
equals $1$ if $(X_1, X_2) \in R_m$, and equals $0$ otherwise.  It is called an indicator function.

Comment: Ah, totally makes for Decision Trees, thanks alot! Does this operator have a name?

Comment: @FrankZalkow  I have only seen it referred to as an Indicator Function (Characteristic Function): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function   It isn't usually thought of as an operator, but I suppose you could conceive of it as an operator that maps sets to functions.

Comment: Thanks! So it would be save (and more conventional according to Wikipedia) to write $\mathbf{1}_{R_m}\big((X_1, X_2)\big)$ instead of $I\{(X_1, X_2) \in R_m\}$?

Comment: Yeah, that would be fine.  So long as $R_m$ is a set of two elements tuples.  You could also probably get away with $1_{R_m}(X_1, X_2)$.

Comment: Great, thanks again!

Comment: @FrankZalkow Happy to help.